# lua mining turtle gps resume script trouble

Tags: lua, gps, minecraft

I am currently learning lua while playing minecraft ftb. i know some basics of lua to be able to make a program but i dont know how to make it restart resistant, so if the server restarts my turtle remembers where it was and resumes with what it was doing.i have looked at many other programs and i desided to use gps setups instead. but how do i get the turtle to resume whith gps? i am currently working on a farming scrip so the turtle will be in a relitive position. and he only moves evry minute to colect and replant the crops.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to save your turtle's state to disk then reload it on startup. There's an API for saving to a file. For instance, to serialize a table to disk:

```
function save(table,name)
   local file = fs.open(name,"w")
   file.write(textutils.serialize(table))
   file.close()
end
```

Comment: how would i go about getting the turtles state and im still new at lua and dont know what the tablebit.